# Curator is not deleting indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am new to curator. I want to see how curator works so installed curator on my mac and I have created one action file and one configuration file to delete all the indices from elastic search.
But whenever I run command

```
curator --config ./config.yml --dry-run ./action.yml
```

I get output as

```
2019-06-27 12:06:49,848 INFO      Preparing Action ID: 1, 
"delete_indices"
2019-06-27 12:06:49,854 INFO      Trying Action ID: 1, 
"delete_indices": Delete selected indices
2019-06-27 12:06:49,866 INFO      DRY-RUN MODE.  No changes will be 
made.
2019-06-27 12:06:49,866 INFO      (CLOSED) indices may be shown that 
may not be acted on by action "delete_indices".
2019-06-27 12:06:49,866 INFO      Action ID: 1, "delete_indices" 
completed.
2019-06-27 12:06:49,867 INFO      Job completed.
```

I thought indices are deleted ,But I can see all the indices on Elastic search.

I cannot see any error It is really difficult to debug

I am sharing both files : 
config.yml

```
---
# Remember, leave a key empty if there is no value.  None will be a 
string,
# not a Python "NoneType"
client:
  hosts:
    - 127.0.0.1
  port: 9200
  url_prefix:
  use_ssl: False
  certificate:
  client_cert:
  client_key:
  ssl_no_validate: False
  http_auth:
  timeout: 30
  master_only: False

logging:
  loglevel: INFO
  logfile:
  logformat: default
blacklist:
```

action.yml:

```
---
# Remember, leave a key empty if there is no value.  None will be a 
string,
# not a Python "NoneType"
#
# Also remember that all examples have 'disable_action' set to True.  
If you
# want to use this action as a template, be sure to set this to False 
after
# copying it.
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: "Delete selected indices"
    options:
    timeout_override: 300
    continue_if_exception: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: age
      source: creation_date
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%W'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 30
```

I created index this week.
Thanks in advance for your help ^^

Comment: You have executed the command with `--dry-run` option. This simulates the action in  action.yml but actually will not make any changes, i.e. will not actually delete index.

Comment: Glad it helped !

Comment: Be very cautious of having only an `age` filter in your delete indices action when `source` is `creation_date`. With no additional filters to exclude the Kibana or other system indices, those will also be deleted when they are older than the specified `unit_count` of `unit` (30 days in your config).  You should have a `pattern` filter _before_ the `age` filter to only delete indices with the expected pattern, excluding system indices.